# Shows a list of data that can be filtered while typing in SearchView Android

Tags: android, searchview

I don't know how to do it so, can someone give me some working codes about **automatically filtering results** when I type a data from the search view and get it from the **`external database`**? Thanks!

Comment: have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/11946289/704374

Comment: How can I connect it to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Use textwatcher on edit text.Compare strings taken by textwatcher in afterTextChange method with your list items .Make new list with matched strings and set it in adapter.Use notifyDatasetChange method on adapter to refresh the list.

Comment: Can you show some codes regarding that? I am new to Android programming that's why I am having a hard time coding from it...